# "Makefile:17146: *** multiple target patterns. Stop." while installing grpc

Tags: git, makefile, grpc

I'm setting up grpc on Windows, but I am getting stuck at the "make" command, which is giving me the error `Makefile:17146: *** multiple target patterns. Stop.`.

Commands I've run:

```
$ git clone -b $(curl -L https://grpc.io/release) https://github.com/grpc/grpc
$ cd grpc
$ git submodule update --init
$ make
```

The make command wasn't found, so I installed it by downloading `make-4.2.1-without-guile-w32-bin.zip` and unzipping, then merging the file content with `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\mingw64\`.

I then tried to run `make` again, but I received the following error:

```
Makefile:17146: *** multiple target patterns. Stop.
```

Then I ran:

```
$ git pull --recurse-submodules
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
$ make
```

and still got the same error on the `make` command.

I have no idea what may be the problem; whether it is with `grpc` or the `make` execution.  Besides trying the above, I looked up most of the discussions on StackOverflow but they all had to do with errors in file names or commands, which isn't the case for me.

Comment: The problem is definitely with `make`—or rather, with the fact that the version you have installed is not compatible with the files in grpc (or in the version of grpc you're using).

Answer (score 0):

The [recommended way to build grpc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/grpc/grpc/+/v1.11.1/INSTALL.md#building-using-cmake-recommended) involves:

> - Install Visual Studio 2015 or 2017 (Visual C++ compiler will be used).
> - Install Git.
> - Install **[CMake](https://cmake.org/download/)**.
> - Install Active State Perl (choco install activeperl) - required by boringssl
> - Install Go (choco install golang) - required by boringssl
> - Install yasm and add it to PATH (choco install yasm) - required by boringssl
> - (Optional) Install Ninja (choco install ninja)

That might work better than make-4.2.1-without-guile.